# Can I dynamically call a local function?

Tags: oop, lua, namespaces, private, public

I have a module that looks like this.  I've simplified it greatly so as not to clutter up my question (my local functions are more complex than this).  Here is my code:

```
decision = {}

function win(win_arg) return win_arg end
function lose(lose_arg) return lose_arg end
local function draw(draw_arg) return draw_arg end

function decision.get_decision(func, arg)
  return func(arg)
end

return decision
```

I am calling my module with the code below.

```
my = require "my-lua-script"

print(my.get_decision(lose, "I lose."))
print(my.get_decision(win, "I win."))
```

I want 'get_decision' to be a public method.  I want `win`, `lose` and `draw` to be private, but I want to call them dynamically from `get_decision`.  If I understand correctly, `win` and `lose` are in the global namespace right now?  If I put a `local` in front of these two methods (like `draw`) then my code doesn't work.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am after?

Comment: You probably want to make `decision` and the other functions local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course.

**my-script.lua**

```
-- This is the local side of the module.
local outcomes = {}

function outcomes.win(arg) return arg end
function outcomes.lose(arg) return arg end
function outcomes.draw(arg) return arg end

-- This is the exposed side of the module.
local M = {}

function M.get_decision(outcome, arg)
  return outcomes[outcome](arg)
end

return M
```

**main.lua**

```
local my = require'my-script'

print(my.get_decision('win', 'I win.'))
print(my.get_decision('lose', 'I lose.'))
```

---

You simply use a string to indicate which function you'd like to access, and use that string to index a table of functions from within `get_decision` against `outcomes`. This will keep the functions hidden behind `get_decision`.

Comment: Thanks!  Not sure I ever would have figured that out.  Glad I asked.  Now I need to know how to dynamically call a module.  Will post another question for that now.